# Code Changes Not reflecting in android studio(MAC)

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-13

First of all I am new to Android studio(1.2.2) so just started on Gradle scripts.

My code changes are not reflecting on my studio when I am running my code on my device after every change.
If I do Build > Rebuild Project it works fine but I get I/O Error everytime looking for my old apt path

```
I/O Error: /Users..../App/build/outputs/apk/......apk (No such file or directory)
```

I have to rename the new apk to the expected name to make it run successfully overtime which is too much work.

This is another issue But First of all I do not want to Rebuild My Project again and again after every code change. On Run the recent code should complile on its own

My build.gradle file has these lines for apk to include variant and version number

```
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
 { output ->
    output.setOutputFile(new File(output.getOutputFile().parent, "${output.getBaseName()}-${getVersionName()}-${project.ext.appCommitsAndHash}.apk"))
}
```

Comment: do you have anything special in your build.gradle regarding apk naming ? (post your build.gradle for better help)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the issue is, and this is only a work-around. But you can install the apk manually via terminal:

```
cd path/to/project_root/build/outputs/apk
adb install -t  -r -d YourApp.apk
```

Comment: I dont want to do that..I want a fix which  which is kind of time saving and not I have to do repeatedly ..

Comment: Also debug doesnt complie the recent code..So i need debugging as well

Comment: I understand. Sorry I couldnt help

Comment: thanks anyways.. But also I do not want to rebuild my project everytime. Run should complile my code changes

Comment: Yes. It does. Or at least it should when working properly